# how would I resolve this error: Unable to contact the RDS server "data services on Tomcat (localhost) connection refused: connect

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, blazeds, weborb

I'm making a program in flash builder 4.5 using WebOrb 4 (which is fantastic, I might add).  When I go to deploy, however, it gives me this error:

```
>There was an error during model deployment for xxxxProgram.
>
>The server returned the following message:
>
>Unable to contact the RDS Server "Data Services on Tomcat (localhost)."
>
>Connection refused: connect
>
>Do you want to continue launching your Flex application?
```

I've poked around online for a solution, but for the most part I either don't understand them (forum grammar can be somewhat obtuse) or the answer in the post doesn't apply.

Any ideas?

Comment: What gives you that error?  Is it a runtime error from the SWF?  Or something else?  Is your SWF using a services-config file that hard codes 'localhost' somehow?

Comment: It's when I go to build the solution in flash builder.

Comment: Do you get this error before the SWF loads?  Are you compiling any services-config file into your app? I didn't notice the RDS distinction in my first review; isn't that a CF Specific feature? Do you have CF builder installed?

Comment: I don't have CF Builder installed, (rather, I don't use it, nor does it show up in the Adobe Master Collection start menu item, which concluded my investigation into it) but I do include weborb-services-config.xml, which includes several other xml files in it.  

I get this error before the SWF loads, and it asks me if I wish to continue trying to build the project.

Comment: CF Builder is not part of the Master collection, to get it you would have had to either buy Flash Builder Premium [separate from Master Collection] or buy it stand alone.  We can assume this is not an issue w/ CF Builder.  I'm unclear why compiling an app would try to ping a remote server.  Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: Hi Corran, how do you run WebORB? Is it work under Jetty (by default), or it works under any different application containers?

Answer (score 1):

the message that you received was thrown by the flash builder and the following part is quite confused:

> "Unable to contact the RDS Server "Data Services on Tomcat
>   (localhost).""

Most likely, the root of the problem is the incorrect server address in your configuration. The WebORB RDS servlet (you are using WebORB for Java, aren't you?) is mapped to the /rds.wo url, so first of all I would recommend to check if the RDS servlet is up. If so, you should verify is your URL from project settings matched to you actual url where WebORB is running .

Additionally, please have a look on the WebORB plugin documentation step by step just to verify if everything is OK. The documentation is available [here](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/java/v4/index.html?flash_builder_integration.htm)

Finally, if you will find nothing, please let me know the version of WebORB that you are using.